# Handling Date in Power-Shell JSON Object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get user info based on LastLogondate from AD. I am converting final output in JSON format.

Here the small script to handle dates. Actually I am passing $PasswordAge as LastLogonDate of the user.

```
 $PasswordAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) # This is actually LastLogonDate from user info
$CurrentDate = (Get-Date)
#Write-Host $PasswordAge
try
{
$LastLogonDays = (New-TimeSpan -Start $PasswordAge -End $CurrentDate).Days
#Write-Host $LastLogonDays
}
catch{
$Message = $_.Exception.Message
}

$JSONOutput = @{"result"=$LastLogonDays;"error"=$Message} | ConvertTo-Json #-Compress
Write-Output $JSONOutput
```

Receiving below error if I use ConvertTo-Json and print output. Day difference is correct but every-time getting message in error

```
 {
    "error":  "Cannot bind parameter \u0027Start\u0027 to the target. Exception setting \"Start\": \"Cannot convert null to type \"System.DateTime\".\"",
    "result":  60
}
```

Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`New-TimeSpan` sucks. I almost always get the same error. It's reported that the issue stems from a mismatch of the culture (language) settings on your OS, the format your OS is configured to use for dates and times, and the format the `DateTime` object is actually in. I live in the US, use the English language, and use our standard format for dates and I still have this problems with getting `New-TimeSpan` to function. I've long-since given up on getting this cmdlet to work consistently.

Fortunately there's an easy workaround; just subtract two datetimes to get a `System.TimeSpan` instead. Works every time.

```
$LastLogonDays = ( $CurrentDate - $PasswordAge ).Days
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am actually trying to find out how many days since user was login last time based on 'LastlogonDate' but while converting final output into JSON getting error. I tried '''[DateTime]::Now''' but still no luck

Comment: @snowcoder You're not getting the error on `ConvertTo-Json`. You're getting the error in `New-TimeSpan`. That happens to me regularly with both its `-Start` and `-End` parameters and I've never found a proper solution other than to not use it. Subtract `$PasswordAge` from `$CurrentDate` instead to get the `TimeSpan` you are looking for.

Comment: Apologies for confusion, I have updated original post with what actually I am trying to achieve. It seems simple '-' is working as you suggested but still new error was captured.